# Как выполнить return c результатом вычисления Си функции внутри блока

Tags: c, objective-c, функции, blocks

Есть функция (Си) в ней асинхронно (GCD) выполняется несколько задач, после выполнения нужно вызвать Return у функции и выдать результат, но если return засунуть в блок он будет относится к текущему блоку. 
Как можно обойти эту проблему и вызвать return с результатом вычисления функции?

```
char mostFrequentCharacter(char* str, int size) {
  ...
  __block char popChar = str[0];
  int i = 0;
  dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
  while (str[i]) {
    __block char curChar = str[i];
    ...
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      ...
      dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            ...
            popChar = curChar;
            });
        });
    }
    i++;
  }
dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
    // Здесь необходимо выдать результат вычисления основной функции
    // return popChar;
  });
}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно оставить задание яндекса выполненным как есть, но обернуть его в Obj-C вызов, типа

```
- (void)mostFreqCharacter: (char*)str size:(int)size completion:(void(^)(char)) {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.queues.mostFreqChar", NULL), ^{
        char result = mostFrequentCharacter(str, size);
        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completion) {
               completion(result);
            }
        });   
    });
}
```

return тут не прокатит, мы же работаем в бакграунде, значит используем completion

В общем и целом создаем группу

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
```

для каждого асинхронного таска делаем enter/leave:

```
dispatch_group_enter(group);
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.queues.someQueueID", NULL), ^{
    /* код в своем потоке */
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
});
```

в конце концов когда все такси сделают leave из группы будет вызван notify, в котором можно дернуть completion c результатом

```
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
```

Comment: Но ведь если выполнить функцию целиком она выполнится в одном фоновом потоке и соответственно не будет удовлетворять одному из условий задания?

Comment: Мне они написали "распараллелить" - в моем понимании это когда мы выполняем какой-то код параллельно с каким-то еще. Но если вопрос ставится так - тогда, ща поправлю ответ